# Auto-start MariaDB using systemd after it has crashed

Tags: centos, mysql, centos7, mariadb

I am trying to set up MariaDB in a way that it automatically recovers -- basically restarts, from a crash.

Based on [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples) -- scroll down to *Auto-starting Services with systemd*, I opened `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mariadb.service` file but there were nothing like this as the article explains:

```
[Service]
...
...
Restart=always
...
```

So I added the `[Service]` section and the `Restart=always` underneath, restarted the service and killed the process to see if it will start automatically, but it didn't.

I was wondering if I'm editing the wrong file or if there are other ways of achieving the same thing. Server is a remote machine running CentOS 7.

Comment: What signal has been used to stop the service? Try SIGSEGV.

Comment: @sam_pan_mariusz `kill -9` oh is that because it wasn't a crash it won't restart?

Comment: I've seen Upstart (the former init program in Ubuntu) not restarting certain services when they received SIGTERM, so I assumed a similar issue may exist with systemd. Other signals however worked as expected, SIGKILL (9) including.

Comment: @sam_pan_mariusz thanks, I will try to see if there are similar solutions for Upstart that I can't apply on systemd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After making changes to systemd units, you need to run `systemctl daemon-reload` for those changes to have effect.